# uvc_camera initialization problem

Tags: ros, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

camera_node fails to launch with the following errors at terminal :

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[uvc_camera-1]: started with pid [2733]
[ INFO] [1342037003.291072134]: camera calibration URL: file:///opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/example.yaml
[ERROR] [1342037003.292045722]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/example.yaml]
[ WARN] [1342037003.292174788]: Camera calibration file /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/example.yaml not found.
opening /dev/video0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  couldn't open /dev/video0
[uvc_camera-1] process has died [pid 2733, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/bin/camera_node __name:=uvc_camera __log:=/home/sudhanshu/.ros/log/7fb92ae8-cb7d-11e1-8f5e-080027007ada/uvc_camera-1.log].
log file: /home/sudhanshu/.ros/log/7fb92ae8-cb7d-11e1-8f5e-080027007ada/uvc_camera-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

tired to run it from root, but it didn't help out.
I am trying to stream images from one PC to another PC..over my LAN. It works sometimes without flaw .. other times it doesn't initialize. Would appreciate some guidance on this. Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38592/uvc_camera-initialization-problem/) by [nanite](https://answers.ros.org/users/2817/nanite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try running ls -l /dev/video0 which should produce this:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 0 Jul 20 19:26 /dev/video0
```

if the first part of the message looks this:

```
crw-rw----
```

like the above then you don't have the correct permissions so type this:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/video0
```

the final message should look like this:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root video 81, 0 Jul 20 19:26 /dev/video0
```

---

Originally posted by [ggamble22](https://answers.ros.org/users/2768/ggamble22/) with karma: 61 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin_chow](https://answers.ros.org/users/34266/kevin_chow/) on 2018-03-22**:
hi, I encountered the same problem, i followed your instruction, it worked, but the camera driver died soon, and i looked up the permissions, it turned out likes this "crw-rw----" again, It bothers me for a long time, do you know why?